# Checking bounds at compile time for fixed size types, but at runtime for dynamic types

Tags: rust

I have a matrix class that can be a vector of vector, or an array of arrays, or some combination of both.

```
pub struct MyMatrix<T>
where
{
    data: T,
}

pub type StaticMatrix<const M: usize, const N: usize> = MyMatrix<[[f32; N]; M]>;
pub type MatrixMX<const M: usize> = MyMatrix<[Vec<f32>; M]>;
pub type MatrixXN<const N: usize> = MyMatrix<Vec<[f32; N]>>;
pub type MatrixX = MyMatrix<Vec<Vec<f32>>>;
```

When implementing std::ops::Add I wanted to add restrictions on bounds at compile time where possible (if the dimensions are both arrays, they must be the same length). Would this require 4x4 implementations of the Add trait? This would likely become more complex because I actually wanted to use expression templates as well, but wanted a minimal example. I wanted to avoid using rust nightly/specialization if possible.

It seems to me the best way to do this is with some form of specialization, but wanted to see if there were other alternatives. If I do need to generate many instances, perhaps I should look into using macros?

Comment: What is the problem with separate `Add` impls? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c1d868bcd044206525191e526d362527

Comment: I believe there would be n^2 implementations (you can add for example a StaticMatrix<2,2> to a MatrixX, provided they are the same size, so there should actually be 16 impls in this example, which seems like a lot to me. (Not including there would be other ops as well such as subtraction and multiplication, and that I wanted to introduce another Matrix return type that would serve as a proxy for lazy evaluation).

Comment: You can use a macro for that. How to construct the macro is a bit complicated, and depends on the details of what exactly you want.

Comment: Defining your own trait implemented by all 4 types might be helpful.